# Does using the shifted power method guarantee that you will find all possible eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

TLDR: Can the shifted power method to loop before finding all possible eigenvalues of a matrix.

Example of what I mean:

Given the shifted power method uses a dominant eigenvalue solver and $\lambda_j$ is the dominant eigenvalue of $A$, it means that for the first shift we find the dominant eigenvalue of $A-\lambda_j\ I$ (assigned $\mu_j$). Now we know from earlier that for all eigenvalues of $A$ (assigned $\lambda_i$) then $\lambda_i-\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A-\lambda_j\ I$. Thus, we know that $\mu_j$ as the dominant  eigenvector (greatest magnitude) must maximise the magnitude output of,
$$\lambda_i-\lambda_j=\mu_j$$

Example, application of method to a matrix $A$ with eigenvalues:
$$\{3,2,-1\}$$

Applying dominant eigenvector solver to $A$ we find $\lambda_j=3$,

Apply shifted power method:
$$2-(3)=-1$$
$$-1-(3)=-4$$
Therefore $\mu_i=-4$ as it has a greater magnitude, thus we find $\lambda_j=-1$

Apply shifted power method:
$$2-(-1)=3$$
$$3-(-1)=4$$
Therefore $\mu_i=4$ as it has a greater magnitude, thus we find $\lambda_j=3$

Apply shifted power method:
$$2-(3)=-1$$
$$-1-(3)=-4$$
Therefore $\mu_i=-4$ as it has a greater magnitude, thus we find $\lambda_j=-1$

Thus, the cycle repeats and we never discover the last eigenvalue $2$.

Does this mean that the shifted power method is not guaranteed to find all the eigenvalues?

Comment: I read a similar-ish question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768882/power-method-for-finding-all-eigenvectors?rq=1, however it talked about other techniques like deflation being used alongside the shifted power method so I just want to be clear this refers solely to the standard method using power scaling to find the dominant eigenvalue of each shifted matrix $A - \lambda_j I$

Comment: Shifted matrices are usually used with the inverse power iteration, or almost equivalently, with the shifted QR method. In the simple power iteration shifts have a rather limited use, as you demonstrated on the example.

Comment: So, my example is valid to show that it doesn't guarantee finding all the eigenvalues?

Comment: With a left and right eigenvector you can reduce the matrix so that it no longer contains the found eigenvalue, and the next-smaller is now the largest. This deflation strategy will only find real eigenvalues, with a complex shift and complex arithmetic you can also find complex eigenvalues. But this is a very inefficient method, the QR algorithms even in the original variant with only one shift at a time are more efficient. There is a topic called "subspace iteration" to find a small number of the largest eigenvalues. But shifting is only a minor concern in the direct power iterations.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, I'm working through a Linear Algebra textbook that covers those strategies later on, so it'll be cool to see some more generally applicable strategies soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the question contains a reasonable counter-example to the suggestion that the power shifting method alongside a power scaling solver will guarantee that all the eigenvalues of a matrix are obtained.